# query inside the variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible in SQL to use a variable to store query.
For example to save time when subquery is used multiple times inside the main query.

Example:

```
DECLARE @my_query as varchar(250) = select x from my_table where my_table = y.your_table
SELECT 
      a,b,c,(@my_query),d,e,f
FROM my_table_1
```

Comment: No, you can't do that. SQL isn't a scripting language, you can use a variable to replace syntax.

Comment: Depending on how/where you are using it:  If the query can be run on its own/stand alone you can run it first and save results into temp table, then in your subquery reference the temp table.

Comment: It isn't possible to use a variable like this. You can of course use a `WITH` clause, which gets close, I think. (And the whole thing would thus become a pure standard SQL compliant query then.)

Comment: Sounds like you want a [Common Table Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: You can use a CTE, or a SQL view.

Comment: Thanks I thought this would be the way but for the sake of saving some lines it was worth a check.

Comment: Why would the same correlated subquery be used multiple times in a query?  That seems very odd.

Comment: @GordonLinoff For example calculations, When I have multiple formulas that use same sub query to get one of the parameters. It would be a handy thing to be able to drop a variable instead of the whole query every time i need that argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible in SQL to use a variable to store query.

Depend on your definition of "query". If you mean store the text which we use to execute the command, then **the answer is YES**. If you mean an object type query, then the answer is not - since there is no data type that fit this.

What I mean is that a variable can store a value which is string. The string can be any query command that you want. Therefore, you can store for example the text "select col1,col2 from table1".

Next you need to ask how can we use this text in order to execute it as part of a query, which is done using **dynamic query**.

We can execute a text of a query using the build-in stored procedure `sp_executesql`, which is build for such needs.

For example:

```
-- DECLARE VARIABLE 
DECLARE @MyQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)
-- SET the value of the variable 
SET @MyQuery = 'SELECT ''Yes I can'''
-- Executing a dynamic query
EXECUTE sp_executesql @MyQuery
```

Here is another example which look more close to your question:

```
-- First let's create a table
CREATE TABLE T(ID INT)
INSERT T(ID) VALUES (1),(2)
GO

-- And here is what you sked about:
-- DECLARE VARIABLE 
DECLARE @MyQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)
-- SET the value of the variable 
SET @MyQuery = 'select ID from T where ID = ''1'''
-- Let's combine the text to a full query now
DECLARE @FullQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @FullQuery = '
SELECT
      ID,(' + @MyQuery + ')
FROM T
'
PRINT @FullQuery
-- Executing a dynamic query
EXECUTE sp_executesql @FullQuery
```

NOTE! Your specific sample of query will return error, which is not related to the question "Is it possible in SQL to use a variable to store query". This is a result of the "query" is not well formatted.

Important! It is HIGHLY recommended to read the document about this stored procedure and learn a bit more of the options it provides us.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for thank you. I have not touched on dynamic SQL yet. I am at the early stages of my SQL journey, but day to day I descover how huge it is, when I always thought about it as just a query language. There seems to be soo muh more to it. Thanks again.

Comment: I glad that I could help @ChefJ `:-)`. Have a great day